# 自作のconfirm画面を作り、promiseを利用して、戻り値を変えたいです。

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

jquery.confirmと言うライブラリーを利用して、confirm画面を作るところまでは良いのですが、クリックした段階でダイアログが出る前に画面遷移してしまいます。

非同期処理で値を返すタイミングをダイアログのボタンを押した後にしたいのですが、どうすればよいかご教示頂けると、幸いです。

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/promise-7.0.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.confirm/jquery.confirm.js"></script>
<link href="../js/jquery.confirm/jquery.confirm.css" rel="stylesheet">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="delet" formaction="userDelete" value="削除" onclick="return chkdelete()">削除</button><br/>
```

```js
function chkdelete() {
  var testV = test().then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  });
  console.log(testV.value);
  return (testV.value = test().then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }));
}

function test() {
  return Confirmation("test").then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  });
}

function Confirmation(messege) {
  var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log("1");
    resolve(false);
  });
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    $.confirm({
      title: "エラーメッセージ",
      message: messege,
      buttons: {
        承認: {
          action: function () {
            resolve(true);
            return false;
          },
        },
        キャンセル: {
          action: function () {
            resolve(false);
            /* キャンセルボタンの処理を記述 */
            // ダイアログを閉じる
            return false;
          },
        },
      },
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一つの案ですが、submitをボタンによる処理にするのではなく、input type="button"としてonclickイベント内でsubmitしてあげれば良いのではないでしょうか？

Comment: Koichiroさん、ありがとうございます。アドバイスを元に問題解決いたしました。アイディアが思い浮かびませんでしたが、非常に助かりました。今後とも精進いたします、ありがとうございました。